# How to update multiple documents with different values in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to execute the following two updates in single update query.

```js
// delete the user with (requestID) from friends
await User.updateOne({
    _id: id,
}, {
    $pull: { friends: requestID }
})

// delete the user with (id) from friends
await User.updateOne({
    _id: requestID,
}, {
    $pull: { friends: id }
})
```

I want it to be like this:

```js
updateMany({
    // delete the user with (requestID) from friends
    // delete the user with (id) from friends
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB's bulkWrite method for this -
[bulkWrite documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/)

```
    await Users.bulkWrite( [
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": {_id: id},
         "update": {"$pull": {"friends": requestId}}
      }
   },
   { updateOne :
      {
         "filter": {_id: requestId},
         "update": {"$pull": {"friends": id}}
      }
   }
] )
```

Comment: thank you a lot I really appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
db.collection.update({},
{
 $pull: {
   friends: {
     $or: [
       {
         id: 1
       },
       {
         requestID: 4
       }
     ]
   }
 }
},
{
  multi: true
})
```

Explained:

$pull the requested different users joining all conditions with $or

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZlAMB5trpfp)